# How to copy vertex colors?

Tags: linked-data, vertex-colors

I duplicated an object with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> several times, then painted some vertex colors on one of the duplicates.

Unfortunately, I think I did this sort of backwards as I can't find a way to copy vertex colors from one object to another.

Is there any way to copy the vertex colors from one object to another identical object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vertex colors are object data, so can be copied/linked with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>*>Object Data*.

This will copy/link all the object data (including mesh data) of the active object to the selected object(s). Doing this after duplicating with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> is the same as duplicating with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.